# how to show thumbnail of video urls from diffrent websites

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have mutliple websites, here what i have to do is like i need to create thumbnail of following video urls

https://nodalview.com/46yDf3CCJoBsRoY9Zgcu7Cnu

https://my.matterport.com/show/?m=4TT8SUrKDez

I explored on mutliple sources like getting thumbnail of youtube video urls and dilay motion video urls but for this they are not working.

```js
generateThumbnail(url){
let videoUrl = url;//from websites that i shared
}
```

```html
<img [src]="here i have to show thumbnail" alt="video thumbnail">
```

Comment: urls is not video